# How can I add payment_id and txn_id to Magento Grid?

Tags: magento-1.8, grid, collection-filtering

I am trying to add `payment_id` and `txn_id` from `the sales_payment_transaction table` to a custom Grid.php module in Magento admin.

I have been able to add the columns which DOES display the data but if I try to search the filter I get an error...

```
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'payment_id' in 'where clause'";
```

Is there a way to make these columns filterable?

Here's my code:

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_payment_transaction',
    'sales_payment_transaction.transaction_id = main_table.entity_id',array('payment_id', 'txn_id'));
```

And here are the columns

```
$this->addColumn('payment_id', array(
    'header'        => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Payment ID'),
    'align'         => 'right',
    'index'         => 'payment_id',
    'filter_index' => 'payment_id',
));

$this->addColumn('txn_id', array(
    'header'        => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Txn ID'),
    'align'         => 'right',
    'index'         => 'txn_id',
    'filter_index' => 'txn_id',
));
```

If anyone knows the solution I'd be grateful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved,

```
 $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('spt'=>'sales_payment_transaction'),
            'spt.transaction_id=main_table.entity_id',array('spt.payment_id', 'spt.txn_id'));
```

And Grid.php columns

```
$this->addColumn('payment_id', array(
    'header'        => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Payment ID'),
    'align'         => 'right',
    'index'         => 'payment_id',
    'filter_index' => 'spt.payment_id',
));

$this->addColumn('txn_id', array(
    'header'        => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Txn ID'),
    'align'         => 'right',
    'index'         => 'txn_id',
    'filter_index' => 'spt.txn_id',
));
```